# how to add an array into an array of json object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, push

```
    var tags = { 

112 :[  
{ "tag":"Shyam", picx: 700, picy: 300 },
{ "tag":"Bob", picx: 340, picy: 120 },  
{ "tag":"Jai", picx: 500, picy: 240 } 
],

114 :[  
{ "tag":"pen", picx: 300, picy: 100 },
{ "tag":"cd", picx: 440, picy: 220 },  
{ "tag":"paper", picx: 600, picy: 440 } 
] };
```

this is the array of objects I have, and I like to add the following into the variable tags

```
115 :[  
{ "tag":"bob", picx: 350, picy: 180 },
{ "tag":"tom", picx: 450, picy: 200 },  
{ "tag":"dave", picx: 620, picy: 430 } 
]
```

I tried

```
tags.push( { 
115 :[  
{ "tag":"bob", picx: 350, picy: 180 },
{ "tag":"tom", picx: 450, picy: 200 },  
{ "tag":"dave", picx: 620, picy: 430 } 
] } );
```

but didn't work

Comment: `tags` is an object not array but `push()` is an array method. Assign as new property `tags[115] = [....]`

Comment: I tried that too, 112 and 114 has three objects but if I try your solution I can add only one, I want to add more dynamically

`tags[115] =  [ { "tag":"box", picx: 550, picy: 180 } ] ;`

but if I do it again, only the last object is there.

Comment: So when the property exists and is array you do `tags[115].push({...})`

Comment: tags[115].push({...}) didn't work, execution stopped at that line.

Comment: Probably because you haven't checked if the property exists. Seems you are asking about two different conditions....how to add when property doesn't exists and how to add when it does. What is source of these objects you want in array?

Comment: from the tag object I posted above, the number is id of an image, and the objects are tags with respective x,y position on the image, so when I add a new tag by clicking on an image , I want to add the id and it's respective tags and positions like the format I posted.

Comment: So you need something like `tags[id] = tags[id] || []; tags[id].push(newobject)`. This will make sure that array exists (either previously created or new one) before pushing

Comment: Just as FYI... it wasn't clear in initial question what the actual use case was since you only asked about adding a new property but now how to update that property if it already existed

Comment: sorry for not being clear, this is my first question on stackoverflow. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`tag` is not Array, however it is object. To add data into object, you need to add a `key`, and then assign data to `key`:

```
var tags = {
    112: [
        { "tag": "Shyam", picx: 700, picy: 300 },
        { "tag": "Bob", picx: 340, picy: 120 },
        { "tag": "Jai", picx: 500, picy: 240 }
    ],

    114: [
        { "tag": "pen", picx: 300, picy: 100 },
        { "tag": "cd", picx: 440, picy: 220 },
        { "tag": "paper", picx: 600, picy: 440 }
    ]
};
```

And add key `115` and assign necessary data:

```
tags[115] = [
    { "tag":"bob", picx: 350, picy: 180 },
    { "tag":"tom", picx: 450, picy: 200 },
    { "tag":"dave", picx: 620, picy: 430 }
];

console.log(`my tags: `, tags)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are making a mistake during adding an array object inside the object and the push method is used for adding an object inside an array.
So, at first, you have to need to convert Object to an array then after you can be able to add array inside array Object.

```
var tags = { 

112 :[  
{ "tag":"Shyam", picx: 700, picy: 300 },
{ "tag":"Bob", picx: 340, picy: 120 },  
{ "tag":"Jai", picx: 500, picy: 240 } 
],

114 :[  
{ "tag":"pen", picx: 300, picy: 100 },
{ "tag":"cd", picx: 440, picy: 220 },  
{ "tag":"paper", picx: 600, picy: 440 } 
]
};
console.log(typeof(tags)); //shows object type
tags=Object.entries(tags);

tags.push({ 
115 :[  
{ "tag":"bob", picx: 350, picy: 180 },
{ "tag":"tom", picx: 450, picy: 200 },  
{ "tag":"dave", picx: 620, picy: 430 } 
] } );
console.log(tags);
```

Comment: `typeof []` is also "object". How is that helpful here? Also what you are pushing to resultant of Object.entries(tags)` is different format. This solution really doesn't seem practical at all

Comment: this solution completely changes the array structure when I post it to PHP, moreover I want to add the array of objects dynamically to the object tags